# Using purrr::map on a function that requires column specification

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use purrr::map() to run a prepackaged function fishmethods::deplet

The dataset has multiple years (see sample below) and I need to fit the model separately for each year.

```
b <- structure(list(Year = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015), BF_AYAs_count = c(37, 12, 7, 8, 13, 4, 3, 6), BF_noT_effort = c(0.445138888899237, 
0.343750000007276, 0.51597222223063, 0.444444444437977, 0.613194444456894, 
0.437499999992724, 0.374999999992724, 0.607638888897782)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

deplet expects the following inputs (catch=NULL,effort=NULL, method = "l") and outputs a list X.out where X == method. For my purposes, I'd like to grab the results ( e.g., l.out$results), by year and put them into a dataframe. Here's the code that I've tried, which returns 
`Error in deplet(catch = BF_AYAs_count, effort = BF_noT_effort, method = "l") : 
  object 'BF_AYAs_count' not found`
I assume that this is an issue stemming from the way the deplet() function expects the data inputs as this code works fine if I substitute `map(data, ~lm(BF_AYAs_count~BF_noT_effort, data=.)` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fishmethods)

bf_AYA_popest <- b %>% 
  nest(-Year) %>% 
  mutate(fit=map(data, deplet(catch=BF_AYAs_count,effort=BF_noT_effort, method="l")),
         results = l.out$results) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
To get around deplet() the issue of not being able to assign the results of deplet to an object, we can wrap deplet in our own function that actually returns the l.out object it always creates to an object we create. Then we can mutate & map our new deplet as you were wanting originally:

```
deplet2 <- function(...){
  deplet(...)
  return(l.out)
}

bf_AYA_popest <- b %>% 
  nest(data = c(BF_AYAs_count, BF_noT_effort)) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~deplet2(catch = .$BF_AYAs_count,
                                 effort = .$BF_noT_effort,
                                 method ="l")),
         results = map(fit, "results"))
```

**OLD**
I will preface this by saying I have never used the fishmethods package or the deplet() function. I think the problem is that I was not able to assign the results of the deplet() to an object (i.e. x <- deplet() always returned x = NULL and an 'l.out' object was ALWAYS created). Because of this I am not sure that this will play nicely inside of the mutate() call. I ended up getting no errors and the code would run with the map inside of mutate, but the results would always be NULL (I am thinking due to the reasons above - not being able to choose the object the results are saved as).

If you are open to it, maybe an alternative suggestion would be to just use a for-loop and build a list of the results separately and then mutate the whole list onto the nested dataframe:

```
#nest the count and effort data
bf_AYA_popest <- b %>% 
  nest(data = c(BF_AYAs_count, BF_noT_effort))

#create an empty list to store results
results_list <- vector("list")
#loop through rows of nested dataframes giving the data to deplete
for(i in 1:nrow(bf_AYA_popest)){

  deplet(catch = bf_AYA_popest$data[[i]]$BF_AYAs_count, 
         effort = bf_AYA_popest$data[[i]]$BF_noT_effort,
         method ="l")
  #each time deplet runs it makes an l.out
  results_list[[i]] <- l.out$results  #catch the ouput and store in list
  #the next run through l.out is overwrritten 
}

#add the list as a  column to the original nested df
bf_AYA_popest <- bf_AYA_popest %>% 
  mutate(fit = results_list)
```

This was my attempt at making this work inside the mutate call:

```
bf_AYA_popest <- b %>% 
  nest(data = c(BF_AYAs_count, BF_noT_effort)) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~deplet(catch = .$BF_AYAs_count,
                                 effort = .$BF_noT_effort,
                                 method ="l")))
```

No errors were thrown but the results were a NULL column:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   Year data             fit   
  <dbl> <list>           <list>
1  2012 <tibble [4 × 2]> <NULL>
2  2015 <tibble [4 × 2]> <NULL>
```

And I would get an 'l.out' object populated in my global environment.

Comment: Thanks, the UPDATE was very helpful and solved my problem. I assume that the "nest" nests by year because it is the only remaining column in the df once the others are assigned to "data".  A note for any folks who might be applying this same function from fishmethods--be sure to update the "METHOD.out" in the wrapper function to match the method applied in deplet() --the sample code I provided uses the "l" method, but the output name changes with method, e.g., method = "ml" output = ml.out.